# A group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I am taking a first course on group theory.

I understand why $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$.

How can I use this fact to show that
$\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ ?

More in general, it looks like (but I am not sure if this is true) that given $\mathbb{G}_1\times\mathbb{G}_2\times\mathbb{G}_3$, I am allowed to take the right most "pair" (i.e. $\mathbb{G}_2\times\mathbb{G}_3$) and replace it with a group isomorphic to it. A sort of associativity rule for the external direct product.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct.  You can prove this pretty easily:  $G \times (L \times M) \cong G \times L \times M \cong (G \times L) \times M$.

Comment: [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Associativity_of_Group_Direct_Product) is a proof of associativity.

Comment: This is (surprisingly) not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The isomorphisms are given by:

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: G\times (H\times K)&\to G\times H\times K,\\
(g, (h,k))&\mapsto (g,h,k);\\
\psi:G\times H\times K&\to (G\times H)\times K,\\
(g,h,k)&\mapsto ((g,h),k);\\
\theta:(G\times H)\times K&\to G\times (H\times K),\\
((g,h),k)&\mapsto (g,(h,k)).
\end{align}$$

Note that the composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism.

Direct products are commutative via $\rho:(g,h)\mapsto (h,g)$.

Given $\pi: M\cong L$, we have

$$P\times M\cong P\times L$$

via $\pi':(p, m)\mapsto (p, \pi(m))$.

Comment: A common mistake is to think the analogous statement to the last one is true for quotients.

Comment: As to the first part,  this is almost comical.    But that's true,  it's all you need to do.   This may be called "canonical".   But that notion still confuses me.